# point position using Kinect V2 camera

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect-interaction

I knew that kinect v2 camera can detect the skeleton joint position, 
but I need to know how can I determine the (x,y,z) position of  a certain point in a room using kinect- v2 camera?

Comment: What language are you use ? C#, C++, VB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take a look at Vitruvius libraries as it has the thing u are looking for like joint position and measuring distance.

> This gets the y coordinate of the left hand joint

Example of joint code: `body.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.Y`

> This gets the distance of the coordinates to the Kinect V2 sensor

Example of distance code: `Length(_bodies[_token.BodyArrIndex].Joints[JointType.SpineBase].Position)`

Vitruvius GitHub link: https://github.com/LightBuzz/Vitruvius

Vitruvius GitHub Gesture joints link: https://github.com/LightBuzz/Vitruvius/tree/master/Kinect%20v2/WPF/LightBuzz.Vitruvius/Gestures

Vitruvius website: https://vitruviuskinect.com/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to use [CameraSpacePoint Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.cameraspacepoint.aspx)

I give you an example in C#.

For that i will track the hand left and i suppose you have your joint.

```
internal Joint HandLeft;
```

For take a position you need to use this:

```
CameraSpacePoint pointLeft = HandLeft.Position;
```

After that you can use your position with this:

```
pointLeft.X
pointLeft.Y
pointLeft.Z
```

of course you can save the value in a float:

```
float test = pointLeft.Y;
```

Comment: In addition to this, if the point is outside the human body (i.e. within the depth frame, you just need to make a similar calculation) - please refer to MSDN pages for the proper documentation

Answer (score 0):

you can determine the (x,y,z) position of 1-25 point of a person in kinect v2.
(Z) means distance from each point to kinect sensor .
if you need find each point of your frame you must use ColorFrame  class then you can define your favorite position with Ellipse of course with a X-Y position.
Your frame is 2D view frame so you dont have z position